# scroll to bottom of tableview after sending message in the cell in swift 4

Tags: uitableview, swift4, chat

I have created chat application in swift 4 for my project. Chat works fine but whenever I send message from textfiled in chat, the recent message don't get visible. I have to scroll down to see the message.

I have used following code:

```
func scrollToBottom(){

  let indexPath = IndexPath(row: self.responseArr.count-1, section: 0)
  self.tblMessage.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)

}
```

But it works only when I load the viewcontroller. But it doesn't work after I send the message from the textfield. I need the message to be seen above the textfield.

Comment: try `self.tblMessage.reloadData()` before `scrollToRow`

Comment: iRiziya@ It reloads full table, i need to show only last sent message in the chat.

Comment: i think you have to append your last message in array before this function call.